# Code para crear <div> dentro de un child theme

Tags: wordpress-theme

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación de Wordpress. He creado un child theme y me gustaría saber cómo puedo crear un nuevo <**div**> en un theme e incrustarlo en una parte de la página web que me interese.

Tan sólo quiero incluir este nuevo <**div**>  evitando con esto modificar el tema padre y que tenga problemas con futuras actualizaciones del theme.

Al contrario, para quitar algunos <**div**> de theme predeterminado, he usado la función:

"display : none"

**Cuestiones:**

1-¿Como puedo crear el <**div**> para incluirlo en la parte de web que me interese?

2-Al contrario, para eliminar un <**div**>  que el Child Theme tiene predeterminado, ¿es correcto realizarlo con la función "*display:none*" dentro de las hojas de estilo?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes hacer es coger el archivo del tema original (padre) y copiarlo en tu carpeta del tema hijo. Una vez ahí, en el tema hijo, puedes modificar el archivo sin que influya sobre el tema padre. Cuando haya actualizaciones, sólo se actualizará el tema padre, por lo que el hijo quedará intacto.

No lo haría con display: none; es una manera sucia de ocultar algo que no se va a ver en ningún momento.

No se si me he explicado del todo bien. Cualquier duda coméntame y te lo resuelvo.